# Cookie gets removed before the expire date in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Something really weird, I had this code work before, after about 2weeks i encountered this problem. I have socket chat and on login i set a cookie for about 10 years gets expired, below is how i set it :

```
   if (!isset($_COOKIE['Token']))
   {
     $user_token  = $user['ID'];
     $token =  md5($user_token,false);
     setcookie("Token",$token,time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
   }
```

Till here it's work fine and getting set on browser and also the expire date is on 2028, So when user try to getting online first he/she will be redirected to `index.php` to check whether there is any cookie for him set or not in order to log him autimatically with the below code :

```
session_start();
if(apache_request_headers()['User-Agent'] !== "TEST") die('Access denied');
// $agent = apache_request_headers()['User-Agent'];
// echo put_contents_file("text.txt",$agent);



    if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn_Username']) OR empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn_Username']) OR $_SESSION['LoggedIn_Username'] == NULL OR $_SESSION['LoggedIn_Username'] == "" OR !isset($_COOKIE['Token']))
    {
      if (isset($_COOKIE['Token']))
      {
        $token = $_COOKIE['Token'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT Username,ID,TOKEN FROM users WHERE TOKEN='{$token}'");
        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        if ($user == true AND $user['TOKEN'] == $token)
        {
          $_SESSION['LoggedIn_Username'] = $user['Username'];
          $_SESSION['My_ID'] = $user['ID'];
          Header('Location: profile.php');
        }else
        {
          Header('Location: logout.php');
        }
      }else
      {
        Header('Location: logout.php');
      }
    }else
    {
      Header('Location: profile.php');
    }
```

Above code will see if the user agent was `TEST` it will allow users to enter, else it will not. After being allowed it will see if the required `sessions` exist or not,if not then `cookie` should help and finding the token from database and set `session` for him again,if `cookie` and `sessions` was not set it will redirect to `logout.php`, But after 2 hours only this cookie `Token` gets removed and i don't know really why this happen, Any idea?

Note: My cookie was UserToken before after i got into this problem i changed it's name to `Token`

Comment: Check what `echo session_name();` gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, The problem was the connection to database, It was unsuccessful...